# 2 list with the recycler view getItemcount method while showing ads?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to show ads in Recycler view but I have two list and I am  getting error while am using the 2 list;
I have ** List serverList ** and ** List recycleItems **and I want to show ads but not able to get the view when I use getItemCount() method of recycler view.

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
        at com.mydata.adapter.ServerAdpter.onBindViewHolder(ServerAdpter.java:123)

```
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("Serv+re", String.valueOf(recycleItems.size() + serverList.size()));
    return recycleItems.size() + serverList.size();
}


public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);

    switch (viewType) {
        case ITEM_data:
            Server server = serverList.get(position);
            ServerViewHolder v = (ServerViewHolder) holder;

            v.bind(position, listener);

        case ITEM_BANNER_AD:

        default:
            AdViewHolder bannerHolder = (AdViewHolder) holder;
            AdView adView = (AdView) recycleItems.get(position); //show error in this line
            ViewGroup adCardView = (ViewGroup) bannerHolder.itemView;
            if (adCardView.getChildCount() > 0) {
                adCardView.removeAllViews();
            }
            if (adView.getParent() != null) {
                ((ViewGroup) adView.getParent()).removeView(adView);
            }
            adCardView.addView(adView);

    }


}
```

Comment: I added more info in response

Answer (score 0):

You can't use recycler view with two lists, it's incorrect.
You can make interface DisplayItem(for example) to store all your items in one list and implement this interface in your classes.

```
public interface DisplayItem

public class Ad implements DisplayItem {

   // Ad properties

}

public class Info implements DisplayItem {

   // Info properties

}


class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

   private List<DisplayItem> items;

   // Your adapter code
}
```

And you work in adapter inly with this list.
In `onBindViewHolder` method you will cast this DisplayItem to desired class for viewHolder

Comment: Thanks for this will try to implement.

Comment: But how I will identify that the data is of list or ad? as items will contain ad and info